# Google Account Registering Bot

Tags: vb.net

thanks for spending time on my post.

I'm currently experiencing a easier way to create a Google account, and apparently there is no Google account creating bot or such thing like that, so I decided to write one my self.(Well, It's not a actual bot, it asks you to manually enter the Captcha.) Then I had a problem when setting a value of a combo box and when grabbing the captcha image to a picture box.....

Here's a part of my code(where the error occurred):

```
    'WebBrowser1 has been navigated to "https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?continue=https:%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount"
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    Dim r As System.Random = New System.Random
    'Sets the value of other textboxes
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(":0").InnerText = MonthSelect(r.Next(1, 12))
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(":d").InnerText = GenderSelect(r.Next(0, 1))
    Captcha.ImageLocation = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("recaptcha_chanllenge_image").GetAttribute("src")
End Sub

Public Function MonthSelect(mon As Integer)
    'Generates a month
End Function

Public Function GenderSelect(gen As Integer)
    'Generates a gender
End Function
```

And the NullReferenceException occurred in these 3 lines...

```
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(":0").InnerText = MonthSelect(r.Next(1, 12))
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(":d").InnerText = GenderSelect(r.Next(0, 1))
    Captcha.ImageLocation = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("recaptcha_chanllenge_image").GetAttribute("src")
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You have a spelling error.

Comment: Please tell me where?

Comment: Thanks, what about the previous two?

Comment: Apparently your element Ids are wrong.  Don't know what else we can tell you.

Comment: I've checked the source code of google account registration page, I think it's right.

Here's a part of source code:
<div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption" id=":0" role="option" aria-setsize="12" aria-posinset="0">Month</div>
............
<div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption" id=":d" role="option" aria-setsize="3" aria-posinset="0">Male</div>

Comment: If I select Female for gender, then it comes to:
 <div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption" id=":d" role="option" aria-setsize="3" aria-posinset="0">Female</div>
So is birthmonth